# Windows 10 work or school account issue

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

Every couple of day I've a notification that my account have a problem:
[image]

Clicking on it opens below window, where it says all accounts are ok
[image]

I don' experience any issues with my account.

Why does it say there is a problem if apparently there isn't one.

I've HP Elitebook 850 G7 with Windows 10 Enterprise 1909.

The problem persists since several months now.

Searching for the problem I found suggestions removing old, unused accounts. I've only one work account added (which I'm using) and two personal ones (@live.com and @gmail.com) both are used and working.

Comment: This notification typically means you have to simply refresh your authentication of your account.  Does it happen on a specific account?

Comment: I have only one work account on the computer, so I suppose it's related to that one. However I don't see how / where it should be refreshed. When I click on the message it already shows everything is fine - probably refresh were done automatically already before I've clicked.

Comment: If the account's authentication needs to refresh it would complain about it within Settings -> Accounts