# How can I change the account from work to personal for Apps & Features "continue app experiences across devices"

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-account

Windows occasionally gives me notifications nagging a windows account has a problem or something.

Answers on Microsofts Q&A site are frustingly inconclusive.

After clicking on the notification, Apps and features shows the following message:

"Sign in with your Microsoft account to continue app experiences across your devices."

[ScreenShot: Apps & Features, Sign in with your Microsoft account to continue app experiences across your devices.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8qpN.png)

However, the MS account OAuth prompt that appears, is an account I've recently removed from One Drive, as it's from a business I no longer have an interest in.

However there is no apparent way to remove it.

[ScreenShot: MS Account OAuth Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjxFU.png)

choosing to use a different account, causes windows to balk at the use of a personal account.

[ScreenShot: MS Account not accepting personal account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDb8y.png)

Additionally, this account was never my primary windows account, so it boggles me that the only advice I can find is "Reset Windows" / Reinstall.

How can I change or remove the account being used, or somehow other disable the warning that Microsoft is warning about?, if it is for features I don't care for.

Related, unanswered windows 10 version: [Windows 10 work or school account issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1698633/windows-10-work-or-school-account-issue)

Answer (score 0):

in the windows search, search for "access work or school"

select the settings result that pops up.

select your account in the list and then click disconnect. Follow the prompts to complete...

My lack of understanding was I didn't know where else it was associated, and it wasn't appearing in the places I expected, it was in it's own awkward corner of settings, and I had only ever used it with onedrive or office 365 so figured removing it via the one drive interface was enough.